# What values do you supply to the sigmoid activation function?

Tags: neural-network

I have my sigmoid activation function:

```
s(x) = 1/(1+e^(-x))
```

I have my output neuron:

```
Expecting = 1
Actual = 1.13
```

I know the value that comes out of the sigmoid activation function is `1.1254` but I can't figure out which values to plug in to get that result.

[image]

Comment: Are you looking for the x for which holds `1/(1+e^(-x)) = 1.1254`?

Comment: I think so. But then the e would still be there, wouldn't it? ...how do they ever get the e out?

Comment: The natural log: `ln(e) = 1`, and exponents just come out as multiplicative coefficients, so `ln(e^-x) = -x`. Is that what you mean?

Comment: @Engineero That's part of it, but there's more to the problem. Typing up answer now.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about math, not programming.

Comment: Apparently somebody else got confused by the same example: http://www.heatonresearch.com/node/3554

Comment: It was the constant e that was throwing me off. I'm gtg now. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E_(mathematical_constant)

Comment: also, they are just rounding when they show 1.13. the actual sum is 1.1254. duh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
x = 1.1254
```

If you plug this `x` into your sigmoid function you get:

```
s(x) = 1 / (1 + e^x)
     = 1 / (1 + 2.71828^(-1.1254))
     = 0.7550
```

The derivative of the sigmoid, `s'(x)` is:

```
s'(x) = s(x) * (1 - s(x)), or
s'(x) = 0.7550 * (1 - 0.7550)
      = 0.1850
```

As @Engineero points out in the comments, `e` is the base of natural logarithms and is approximately equal to `2.71828`.